# Upto which generation of ancestos above is the Pind-Daan offered?

Tags: pitru

Upto which generation of ancestors above one is the Pind-daan offered ? What happen to people who are above it ? How do they eat in Pitri-Loka ?

Answer (score 0):

It would be three generations (father/mother, grandfather/grandmother and great grandfather/great grand mother) but if you want to go beyond you can. While we uniquely identify the three generations before us, we do also identify the one before them as all other ancestors and Pind-daan applies to all above or anyone remain in pitru-loka (astral-realm). It is said that three generations are the ones who remain in the pitru loka and the rest attain salvation.

We all live in different realms, bhuloka (us), pitru loka (ancestors) etc. and when it comes to accepting the offerings it happens through different forms, like us they are beings too but at a different level and have means to absorb energy from the offering.

Justification to moderators - this answer is original and needs no citations, the knowledge is acquired from previous generations. I also request that not every answer posted here is to be supported with citations as authentic text themselves were also written by people like us. The technicality of my posts rely on logic and my clear understanding in the modern world, yet how I uphold the Hindu dharma, thank you.